# unable to find and open bluetooth connection simultaneously on single tap

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Friends i am connecting arduino bluetooth and fetching data in the android  app. which i have done successfully. But one single tap of button bluetooth 
gets connected to device and on tapping again i get the data fetched. I want 
it on single tap/click. I tried many possibilities. Here's my code.

```
public void BT_connect(View v) throws IOException {
    findBT();
    openBT();

}



void findBT() throws IOException {
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No bluetooth adapter available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
    }

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            if (device.getName().equals("HC-05")) {
                mmDevice = device;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Health Assistant Device HC-05 Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;

            }}}





}

void openBT() throws IOException {

    try {


        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
        mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        mmSocket.connect();
        mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

        beginListenForData();


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

void beginListenForData() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                try {
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                    if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if (b == delimiter) {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {

                                        try {
                                            String[] separated = data.split(",");
                                            String humidity=separated[0].trim();
                                            String tempdata = separated[1].trim();
                                            pulsedata = separated[2].trim();
                                            tempvalue.setText(tempdata);
                                            humidityvalue.setText(humidity);


                                            if(pulsedata.equals("0")){pulsevalueText.setText(null);}
                                            else{
                                                pulsevalueText.setText(pulsedata);}


                                            Double i = Double.valueOf(tempdata);
                                            Double F = i * 1.8 + 32;
                                            DecimalFormat ff = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
                                            String formattedValue = ff.format(F);
                                            fahrenheit.setText(formattedValue);



                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();
}
```

Comment: unable to post all code gives lot of indent space error. i tried to correct but cant.. so this much code.

Comment: and what is a problem in this code?  It is not obvious, what happens.

Comment: Hi..thanks for response.. by executing BT_connect i want to enable bluetooth as well connect and receive data... currently i need to execute BT_connect again to get data.. any idea..

Comment: firstly, you ignore the exceptions, which should tell you what is the problem. at least `e.printStackTrace()` them.

Comment: that is not my problem.. i am new to coding.. so dont know what exactly i should say here.. It is like when i hit a button to connect the bluetooth and again i need to hit the same button to get the data displayed in the text. That means somelthing is not executing simultaneosly. I tried to put openBT() inside the findBT() to execute simultaneosly.. but again it is failure.